# having some issues adding mysql data to JTables

Tags: java, swing

I am learning how to connect to a database, and as a project I am making a JTable display database information. I am using a database called world that has a table called city with columns id, name, countrycode, district, population. Here is my code, I made it after looking at the java doc and some other various sources, but I am not sure if I am doing it right, and I have never used vectors before either.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class JTableTest extends JFrame {
    Vector<String> columnNames;
    Vector<Object> row;
    JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTableTest test = new JTableTest();
        test.connectDB();

    }

    public void buildGui() {
        setSize(500, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void connectDB() {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/world";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "root";
        String sql = "Select id, name, countrycode, district, population  from city where id < 100";
        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            System.out.println("connecting..");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            System.out.println("connected!");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            table = new JTable(rsToTableModel(rs));

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public TableModel rsToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = md.getColumnCount();
            columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
                columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnLabel(i));
            }
            row = new Vector<Object>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));                    
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new DefaultTableModel(row, columnNames);
    }
}
```

Here is my error

```
connecting..
connected!
[1, Kabul, AFG, Kabol, 2, Qandahar, AFG, Qandahar, 3, Herat, AFG, Herat, 4, Mazar-e-Sharif, AFG, Balkh, 5, Amsterdam, NLD, Noord-Holland, 6, Rotterdam, NLD, Zuid-Holland, 7, Haag, NLD, Zuid-Holland, 8, Utrecht, NLD, Utrecht, 9, Eindhoven, NLD, Noord-Brabant, 10, Tilburg, NLD, Noord-Brabant, 11, Groningen, NLD, Groningen, 12, Breda, NLD, Noord-Brabant, 13, Apeldoorn, NLD, Gelderland, 14, Nijmegen, NLD, Gelderland, 15, Enschede, NLD, Overijssel, 16, Haarlem, NLD, Noord-Holland, 17, Almere, NLD, Flevoland, 18, Arnhem, NLD, Gelderland, 19, Zaanstad, NLD, Noord-Holland, 20, Â´s-Hertogenbosch, NLD, Noord-Brabant, 21, Amersfoort, NLD, Utrecht, 22, Maastricht, NLD, Limburg, 23, Dordrecht, NLD, Zuid-Holland, 24, Leiden, NLD, Zuid-Holland, 25, Haarlemmermeer, NLD, Noord-Holland, 26, Zoetermeer, NLD, Zuid-Holland, 27, Emmen, NLD, Drenthe, 28, Zwolle, NLD, Overijssel, 29, Ede, NLD, Gelderland, 30, Delft, NLD, Zuid-Holland, 31, Heerlen, NLD, Limburg, 32, Alkmaar, NLD, Noord-Holland, 33, Willemstad, ANT, CuraÃ§ao, 34, Tirana, ALB, Tirana, 35, Alger, DZA, Alger, 36, Oran, DZA, Oran, 37, Constantine, DZA, Constantine, 38, Annaba, DZA, Annaba, 39, Batna, DZA, Batna, 40, SÃ©tif, DZA, SÃ©tif, 41, Sidi Bel AbbÃ¨s, DZA, Sidi Bel AbbÃ¨s, 42, Skikda, DZA, Skikda, 43, Biskra, DZA, Biskra, 44, Blida (el-Boulaida), DZA, Blida, 45, BÃ©jaÃ¯a, DZA, BÃ©jaÃ¯a, 46, Mostaganem, DZA, Mostaganem, 47, TÃ©bessa, DZA, TÃ©bessa, 48, Tlemcen (Tilimsen), DZA, Tlemcen, 49, BÃ©char, DZA, BÃ©char, 50, Tiaret, DZA, Tiaret, 51, Ech-Chleff (el-Asnam), DZA, Chlef, 52, GhardaÃ¯a, DZA, GhardaÃ¯a, 53, Tafuna, ASM, Tutuila, 54, Fagatogo, ASM, Tutuila, 55, Andorra la Vella, AND, Andorra la Vella, 56, Luanda, AGO, Luanda, 57, Huambo, AGO, Huambo, 58, Lobito, AGO, Benguela, 59, Benguela, AGO, Benguela, 60, Namibe, AGO, Namibe, 61, South Hill, AIA, Â–, 62, The Valley, AIA, Â–, 63, Saint JohnÂ´s, ATG, St John, 64, Dubai, ARE, Dubai, 65, Abu Dhabi, ARE, Abu Dhabi, 66, Sharja, ARE, Sharja, 67, al-Ayn, ARE, Abu Dhabi, 68, Ajman, ARE, Ajman, 69, Buenos Aires, ARG, Distrito Federal, 70, La Matanza, ARG, Buenos Aires, 71, CÃ³rdoba, ARG, CÃ³rdoba, 72, Rosario, ARG, Santa FÃ©, 73, Lomas de Zamora, ARG, Buenos Aires, 74, Quilmes, ARG, Buenos Aires, 75, Almirante Brown, ARG, Buenos Aires, 76, La Plata, ARG, Buenos Aires, 77, Mar del Plata, ARG, Buenos Aires, 78, San Miguel de TucumÃ¡n, ARG, TucumÃ¡n, 79, LanÃºs, ARG, Buenos Aires, 80, Merlo, ARG, Buenos Aires, 81, General San MartÃ­n, ARG, Buenos Aires, 82, Salta, ARG, Salta, 83, Moreno, ARG, Buenos Aires, 84, Santa FÃ©, ARG, Santa FÃ©, 85, Avellaneda, ARG, Buenos Aires, 86, Tres de Febrero, ARG, Buenos Aires, 87, MorÃ³n, ARG, Buenos Aires, 88, Florencio Varela, ARG, Buenos Aires, 89, San Isidro, ARG, Buenos Aires, 90, Tigre, ARG, Buenos Aires, 91, Malvinas Argentinas, ARG, Buenos Aires, 92, Vicente LÃ³pez, ARG, Buenos Aires, 93, Berazategui, ARG, Buenos Aires, 94, Corrientes, ARG, Corrientes, 95, San Miguel, ARG, Buenos Aires, 96, BahÃ­a Blanca, ARG, Buenos Aires, 97, Esteban EcheverrÃ­a, ARG, Buenos Aires, 98, Resistencia, ARG, Chaco, 99, JosÃ© C. Paz, ARG, Buenos Aires]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at JTableTest.rsToTableModel(JTableTest.java:80)
    at JTableTest.connectDB(JTableTest.java:51)
    at JTableTest.main(JTableTest.java:22)
```

My first question is am I doing the vectors right? I am not sure if its supposed to add everything to the row vector as just one huge entry separated by commas. Am I approaching this right? I feel like I am missing something ..I am assuming I get this error because the object has 5 columns including ints and strings, but not sure where to go from here. All I know is a Jtable accepts (vector,vector) or (object[][],object(). I am getting confused as its my first time working with mysql and jtables.

Comment: `Am I approaching this right?` The first thing you should do is to create a concreate TableModel (subclass of `javax.swing.table.TableModel` or `javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel`, so that the TableModel itself controlls the content of the data Vectors.) Check out some examples about a custom TableModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> row = new Vector();

- representing single row, not 2D set of rows
- you have to create 2D array e.g.  `Vector<Vector<Object>>() data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();`, then add a `new row = new Vector<Object>()`; to `Vector<Vector<Object>>();` after data are filled inside `while (rs.next()) {`
- change return `new DefaultTableModel(row, columnNames);` to return new `DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);`
- override `getColumnClass` for `DefaultTableModel`
- don't reinvent the wheel, search for `ResultSetTableModel`, `TableFromDatabase`

Comment: Thank you, is it necessary to rename row>data or is it just for being cleaner. Also, why do I override getColumnClass, I am not sure why this is mentioned

Answer (score 1):

According to the method definition mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29), the first argument of **DefaultTableModel** constructor should be a Vector of Vectors.

In your while loop declare another Vector variable

```
while (rs.next()) {
     java.util.Vector<Object> rowData = new java.util.Vector<Object>();
     for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
         rowData.addElement(rs.getObject(i));                    
     }
     // Here add that row data to the row vector
     row.addElement(rowData);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I gave the answer to korbel because he answered first, but your answer made me understand his better, so I didn't realize what he meant by vector<vector<object>>, thanks

Comment: No worries. You understood the concept. That is sufficient. Good luck.